# Remove a 0 from a Flex Datagrid when no results are displayed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, null

I have a flex datagrid that is populated from a database using several queries, this works perfectly however if their is no searh results returned several of the cells will return a 0. these cells have a labelfunction applied to them and I need all cells to be returned as blank when no results are returned.

Comment: can you post your labelfunction code?

Comment: private function quantity_amountformatter(inData:Object, inCol:AdvancedDataGridColumn)
   {
    var qtyAsNumber:Number = Number(inData.COLUMN_HEADER);
    return (isNaN(qtyAsNumber)?"":qtyAsNumber.toString());
   
   }

Comment: labelfunction is working fine. If no search result returned then what you are doing to the dataprovider?

Comment: the dataprovider is null, lenght 0 etc. the cell worked as expected before the label function was added, but it is essential

Comment: In my environment it is working fine with the your labelfunction even when the dataprovider is set to null. Hope you are not using any itemrenderer. Can you post your datagrid code and any other related code

Comment: I havent used an item renderer. below is some code. thanks

Comment: mxml : <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Quantity Amount" dataField="QUANTITY_AMOUNT" labelFunction="quantity_amountformatter"/>    as :  ViewGridCanv.query = Query;
   ViewGridCanv.addParameter(Parameter, "");
   ViewGridCanv.itemID = displayItems.indexOf(ViewGrid);

Comment: Validate the dataprovider in the result function, not the labelfunction...

Comment: what do you mean by validate the dataprovider?